# Problem with birt report in PDF format

Tags: birt

I am creating a report in BIRT. My problem is a data set value which I am putting inside a table column. The returned value is a sentence, but in my report that column is showing only the first word. How can I break the line of the column to show the full data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Dynamic Text instead of Data field, which I assume you were using.

As expression write something like `row["MY_COLUMN"]`.